# Triggering Hangfire Jobs using SQL

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api, hangfire

I have a **Hangfire** service running on one of my servers, I'm a DBA and sometimes I'm asked to trigger jobs using the Dashboard, but it takes me a lot of time to connect to the jobs' server due to some connectivity and security issues.
And to overcome that, I want to trigger those jobs by inserting in **Hangfire's** tables on the database, I can already query those tables to find which job executed when and whether they failed, succeeded or still enqueued, does anyone know an approach to do so?

I've included a sample of two tables which I think will be used to do this trick, their names are `Hash` and `Set` respectively:

[image: "Hash" Table]

[image: Set Table]

Answer (score 1):

Hangfire normally uses a gui like swagger in .net (**http://localhost:5000/hangfire**) , there should be a immediate trigger feature. If not a second option is changing the cron expression for every minute or maybe every 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks firatt for the info, could you please share a tutorial about the "cron", I think it's like linux but I actually don't know how to use it.

Comment: as shown in screenshot you already have cron expression according to which the jobs will be executed every day at midnight. do you really want to change the cron expression to execute every min. for me it is not clear when do want to retrigger the job only failed job or every job ?

Comment: @Poseidon You can search cron expression generator . Like this search every 3 minutes cron expression , or every 1 . 15 AM cron expression

Comment: the scenario I have in mind is changing the schedule to run like every 5 min, then after the job executes I'll revert it back to previous setting, it's way easier than connecting to the server to fire the job via dashboard

Comment: @Poseidon and you would change it directly in the sql database ?

Comment: @Nitz Yes, it's the easier option

Comment: you have to be very careful because changing cron expression in database could have some other impact as other values like nextexecution are calculated based on this and once this is set to some value in future then it might not trigger the job untill that time.

Comment: My approach would be saving the current cron exp and then updating with desired value, after the execution finishes I will revert back to previous value, I guess this would be a safe way